# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename

Tags: ionic, file-permission

Fui tentar rodar o ionic run android e  estou com o seguinte erro:
Já liberei todas as permissões de acesso com o usuário.

```
    C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Casa\.config\configstore\update-notifier-cordova.json.3156381432' -> 'C:\Users\Casa\.config\configstore\update-notifier-cordova.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:809:18)
    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\write-file-atomic\index.js:124:8)
    at Object.set (C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\configstore\index.js:62:21)
    at Object.Configstore.del (C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\configstore\index.js:99:11)
    at UpdateNotifier.check (C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\index.js:55:15)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\index.js:124:17)
    at checkForUpdates (C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:80:24)
    at cli (C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:272:5)
    at C:\Users\Casa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:202:16
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

Answer (score 2):

Fui até essa pasta `C:\Users\<user>\.config\configstore\`. Cliquei com lado direito do mouse > Propriedades > Geral, e desmarquei o checkbox "**Somente Leitura (Arquivos da pasta)**"

Fiz isso mais de uma vez enquanto tentava buildar meu app. Até que deu certo.